# How does google know my real location even using VPN

Tags: vpn, privacy

If I google search "time right now", it shows accurate time, along with my location (which is in India). But if I install a VPN on my chrome and access through US based IP-address, it does not show US time. But it shows other search results, that are related specifically to my location/timezone! How does it know that?

I have tried all of the following:

- Set my computer's timezone to GMT-5
- Cleared all browsing data, even infact created new user in chrome.
- Restarted browser many times.

Even after doing all above (in every order), following snapshot is the result:

*Update: Following is my hypothesis: Browser based VPN extensions start a few seconds after the browser starts. And in this time lapse, chrome makes a ping to google's server, and reports its identity and IP address. After that, no matter what location I use on VPN, google shows search results relevant to my original IP address. I figured this out when I finally installed a VPN on the OS. After that, I restarted chrome, and search results were then based on US, exactly how it should be.*

[image: Google knows my location even using VPN]

Answer (score 3):

It gets the information from your browser which gets it from your operating system.

If you change the information on your PC and you restart your browser, you'll get a different result.

I've done it myself in a web application where time is important.  I check their browser's timezone with the timezone configured for their account (if any) and notify when there is a difference in the timezones.