# How does my browser know my location when I am on VPN?

Tags: vpn, browser, geolocation

I saw a similar question ([How does google know my real location even using VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1254665/how-does-google-know-my-real-location-even-using-vpn)) but I don't think it quite answers the question.

I want to know how does my browser know my geo location when I am on VPN even before the browser starts. I originally thought that it figures out base on my IP. But when VPN is enabled, all traffic is tunneled through VPN  and my public IP is the VPN peer's IP instead of my ISP assigned IP but my browser still knows my very accurate location.

Comment: Your browser knows your location because your location isn't determined based on information about IP Address in most cases.  Window and most mobile devices use your access points around you to determine your location.  The other possibility is the VPN is configured to leak your information.

Comment: How do you test if the browser really knows your geolocation? Some websites guess your country from your language setting.

Answer (score 3):

Using a VPN is not enough to be secure on a standard operating system.

Several factors can lead to the pinpointing of your location. Some of these are;

1. DNS leaks https://www.dnsleaktest.com/
2. Web RTC leaks https://www.expressvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test
3. IPv6 leaks http://ipv6leak.com/

You can configure an OS such as Windows 10 to mitigate these leaks. However, this is difficult to track down and change, updates can reset your changes, and the above changes lead to an undesirable UX.

So if you are doing anything that will potentially lead you to be accused of treason, I'd suggest using an OS designed solely for privacy purposes, e.g Tails